# "No network connections available" Missing driver

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm currently running the newest version of Ubuntu, and I'm not able to use my network device on my Asus notebook. When I use the sudo lshw - see network command I am told that currently the network device is unclaimed. I know that this mean there is currently no driver installed for my current network device. My main problem with finding a solution is that I do not have an Ethernet port to get the required drivers for this to work. I've tried mounting the Ubuntu ISO that I installed with in using that to get the back packages to install the drivers, but to no avail. Also I cannot give any output unless I type them hand into my phone because that is how I'm using to ask a question.

I've found the driver I needed for my wirless adapter. I found it here:http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1796 I assumed since linux mint is based on Ubuntu it would work, but every time I try to install it freezes. So I'm one step closer I guess.

Another update. I've found out that the driver in that last link was for the wrong kernal. I'm currently running 4.2, and from what I can find there is not a working driver for my device(MT7630e) on this kernal. If anyone can find one that will be greatly appreciated.

I've learned more things. That this driver should work for the new kernal, but only for WiFi(this is what I want). At this point I'm getting this error

```
    keith@keith-Q302LA:~/Downloads/MT7630E_3.16-master$ make installsudo cp firmware/Wi-FI/MT7650E234.bin /lib/firmware/
cd rt2x00 && make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/keith/Downloads/MT7630E_3.16-master/rt2x00'
make -C /lib/modules/4.2.0-16-generic/build M=/home/keith/Downloads/MT7630E_3.16-master/rt2x00 modules
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/keith/Downloads/MT7630E_3.16-master/rt2x00/rt2x00mac.o
/home/keith/Downloads/MT7630E_3.16-master/rt2x00/rt2x00mac.c: In function ‘rt2x00mac_configure_filter’:
/home/keith/Downloads/MT7630E_3.16-master/rt2x00/rt2x00mac.c:365:6: error: ‘FIF_PROMISC_IN_BSS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
      FIF_PROMISC_IN_BSS;
      ^
/home/keith/Downloads/MT7630E_3.16-master/rt2x00/rt2x00mac.c:365:6: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/home/keith/Downloads/MT7630E_3.16-master/rt2x00/rt2x00mac.o' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/keith/Downloads/MT7630E_3.16-master/rt2x00/rt2x00mac.o] Error 1
Makefile:1398: recipe for target '_module_/home/keith/Downloads/MT7630E_3.16-master/rt2x00' failed
make[2]: *** [_module_/home/keith/Downloads/MT7630E_3.16-master/rt2x00] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic'
Makefile:29: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/keith/Downloads/MT7630E_3.16-master/rt2x00'
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'wifi_compile' failed
make: *** [wifi_compile] Error 2
```

I'm not 100% sure what this means, but it does get me closer.

Comment: Finding sex? Could you please give us the output of `sudo iwconfig` (should be something like lo, eth0, wlan0)?

Comment: Oops sorry I am typing on a mobile phone so typos. Also the output to that is: "lo         no wireless extensions"

Comment: That's bad, but not hard to solve.. You don't have the appropriate drivers. Could you please give me the output of `dmesg | grep "Ethernet Driver"`?

Comment: There was no output

Comment: You use wired connection, right? If there's no output, it got pretty hot. What about `dmesg | grep "Ethernet"`? And tell me the brand/name/model of your network card, if available.

Comment: Also try `dmesg | grep "Network"`.

Comment: Hmm, no I do not have a wired connection. That's why doing this is a problem.

Comment: So what do you have? How are you supposed to connect to the internet in your computer?

Comment: Also the output to dmesg | feel "Network" is: audit: type=1400 audit(1452510132.073:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=527 comm="apparmor_parser"

Comment: I have a wireless extensions, that has no driver.

Comment: I've updated my thread, and am trying to give more info.

Answer (score 0):

Finally back on a laptop which makes this wonderful. So Ive figured it out, and it took me way to. long https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E was the driver I needed to use, but since it was for a different kernal it did not work right away. After going to it in my directory I did the command `sudo make clean` after I did this I could finally install it without a problem. I restarted my computer, and everything has been working smoothly.